# How to refer to previous state in React's child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

Let's say I have this component:

```
class MyForm {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>Remember my Setting</h3>
        <Toggle
         value={this.state.rememberMe}
         onClick={() => {
           this.setState(prevState => ({ rememberMe: !prevState.rememberMe }));
         }}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I pass this prevState if its wrapped in child component? Is this acceptable?

```
class MyForm {
  render() {
    return (
      <PartialForm
        onClick={(v) => {
          this.setState({ rememberMe: v });
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

const PartialForm = (props) => {
  return (
      <>
        <h3>Remember my Setting</h3>
        <Toggle
         value={props.rememberMe}
         onClick={() => {
           props.onClick(!props.rememberMe);
         }}
        />
      </>
  );
}
```

I want to know if accessing props.rememberMe is the same and safe as accessing prevState.rememberMe in parent component. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the way you're doing is safe and it has no conflicts at all.

I can simply demonstrate those re-rendering steps here:

- Pass the current state to `PartialForm`
- Trigger toggle click `props.onClick` for updating `rememberMe` in the upper component
- The upper component gets re-rendered, and then your child component will have the latest state of `rememberMe`

By the way, you also forget to pass `rememberMe` in `<PartialForm />`

```
class MyForm {

  render() {
    return (
      <PartialForm
        rememberMe={rememberMe}
        onClick={(v) => {
           this.setState({ rememberMe: v });
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

const PartialForm = (props) => {
  return (
      <>
        <h3>Remember my Setting</h3>
        <Toggle
         value={props.rememberMe}
         onClick={() => {
           props.onClick(!props.rememberMe);
         }}
        />
      </>
  );
}
```